# How to output each data to a file accordingly?

Tags: c++, file, outputstream, ofstream, file-io

```
struct GPattern() {
    int gid;
    ....
}
class Example() {
public:
    void run(string _filename, unsigned int _minsup);
    void PrintGPattern(GPattern&, unsigned int sup);
    ....
};

Eample::run(string filename, unsigned int minsup) {
    for(...) {    // some condition
        // generate one GPattern, and i want to ouput it
        PrintGPattern(gp, sup);
    }
}

Example::PrintGPattern(GPattern& gp, unsigned int sup) {
    // I want to ouput each GPattern to a .txt file
}
```

`run` is used to generate a `GPattern` accordingly.

What I want to output to a file is some texts that reconstruct the original `GPattern`.

I can't store all `GPattern` in advance and output all of them. I have to output one `GPattern` to a file when I generate it, but I don't know how to implement it.

I have tried to declare `ofstream outGPatter("pattern.txt")` in class `Example`, but it is of no use...

Comment: I don't want to replace original `GPattern` in the .txt file

Comment: I see many holes in your question. I think I got the answer for you but I am not confident enough with those many holes.

Comment: Can you tell me your thought? Thanks:)

Comment: In @s3rius method, original data will be replaced, but i want to retain them and add new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ofstream is the right way to go:

```
Example::PrintGPattern(GPattern& gp, unsigned int sup) {
    ofstream outGPattern("pattern.txt")

    outGPattern << gp.gid; << " " << gp.anotherGid << " " ....

    outGPattern.close()
}
```

Have you looked at the correct place for the pattern.txt? It should either be in the folder where your .exe is, or in the folder where all your .h and .cpp files are (for VS at least).

If you want to write all patterns into the same file then you need to make sure you append (and not overwrite) the pattern.txt

> ofstream outGPattern("pattern.txt",ios::app)

So you can first make an ofstream without ios::app (to clear the textfile) at the start of your program. Then you construct all other ofstreams with ios::app to append new text, instead of overwriting it.

Alternatively you can make the ofstream a member variable of Example. Then you construct it only once.

Comment: But in your method, original data will be replaced, so i can only get the latest GPattern.

Comment: You have to use ios::app if you don't want it replaced. Making an edit.

Comment: Can i ask you another question? How to print the string to the screen and output the string to a file simultaneously??


The naive method is use `cout` and `outfile` simultaneously, but i will cause redundant code. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.mr. it doesn't really add redundant code. It's true that both are streams, but one is directed towards a file, the other towards the console. The text must be printed twice anyway. I don't know if there's a way to redirect the stream to write to both at once, but if there is it's probably very messy. Just make a helper function which writes a given string into both.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use append mode, such as:

```
ofstream outGPattern;
outGPattern.open("GPattern.txt", ios::app);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you want to *append* information of multiple `GPattern` and you simply need to set the I/O mode to `ios::app` in the constructor.

```
struct GPattern {
  int gid;
  friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& o, GPattern gp) {
    return o << "(gid=" << gp.gid << ")";
  }
  ...
}

Example::PrintGPattern(GPattern& gp, unsigned int sup) {
  ofstream fout("pattern.txt", ios::app)
  fout << gp << endl;
  fout.close()
}
```